# Why does getHeight() method not work in the constructor?

Tags: java, methods, constructor, acm-java-libraries

This is the code:

```
    import acm.program.*; 

    public class test extends GraphicsProgram{ 

        public test(){ 

           println(getHeight()); 

        } 

        public void run(){ 

          println(getHeight()); 

        } 

    }
```

The executed result is `0 472`. Why does `getHeight()` in the constructor return `0`, whereas `run()` returns `472`, which is the real value?

Comment: Perhaps height hasn't been set in the constructor when you print it.

Comment: This is not even a proper Java code snippet. And what is `GraphicsProgram`?

Comment: http://jtf.acm.org/javadoc/student/acm/program/GraphicsProgram.html

Answer (score 6):

The height has not been set until the `init()` method, which executes before the `run()` method.

Comment: What if I have to call getHeight() method without having run() method, e.g: the class **test** is used as a subclass, which not necessarily has a run() method; and main class is gonna create an object of this class **test** with getHeight() method actually functioning.

Comment: Override the `init()` method of the subclass, making sure to call `super.init()` before trying to access the `getHeight()` method.

Comment: Bear with me but I failed again.. here is my code: 1)(class to be used)`import acm.graphics.*;

public class test extends GCanvas{ 
 public int x;
 public void init(){  
  x = getHeight();      
 }  
}
`  2)(main executive class)`import acm.program.*;

public class test2 extends ConsoleProgram{    
 public void run(){
  test a = new test();
  a.init();
  println(a.x);  
 } 
}`  which still returns a zero....

Comment: You are extending a different class now, but basically where you have `public void init(){ x = getHeight(); }` call `public void init(){ super.init(); x = getHeight(); }`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this really drives me crazy... when i try to add the line `super.init();` Eclipse says that init() is undefined for the type GCanvas.. so I change the GCanvas back to GraphicsProgram. The warning from Eclipse goes away, but when I run the program test2, getHeight() still returns a zero..

Comment: Sorry that I couldn´t help you, the only other thing I would suggest is to use a debugger and some watches to see when the height is getting initialized.

Answer (score 0):

An item doesn't have a height at first. Most likely you are calling getHeight() before the component is laid out or given a height.

Comment: What if I have to call getHeight() method without having run() method, e.g: the class **test** is used as a subclass, which not necessarily has a run() method; and main class is gonna create an object of this class **test** with getHeight() method actually functioning.

Comment: A subclass of test will always have a run method because test has a run method.  Either way, something will need to set the height before you can access the value.

Comment: sorry for using the misleading word subclass .. bear with a starter .. what I really mean is another class, named main_class(with run method), which do not have the hierarchical relationship. The *main_class* is gonna create an object of the class *test*(without run method). What to do if I want getHeight() in *test* class take its function.

Comment: Both examples are completely unrelated to the core problem.  I don't think you understand what the code is actually doing.